# TypeScript definitely typed (.d.ts) files build action in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

Using an ASP MVC 5 project in VS 2013 update 4, I've just added my first .ts files, and also jquery.d.ts in my /Scripts/typings/jquery. Then updated my tsc to 1.4. All OK, in .csproj file `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>` was set and the 100s errors in jquery.d.ts has gone.

My question: Can I set TypeScript definitely typed (.d.ts) files build action to 'none' instead 'TypeScriptCompile' to prevent compiling them unnecessary? (Yes... I have no idea about how is this working, but *if* this is similar thing how C/C++ include header files work, then my question makes sense.)

I've also tried to locate where the output of this compile build step (for jquery.d.ts) is located. My goal was to determine whether this compile step executed always or just in case if the .d.ts file is changed. If it is only recompiled in case if the .d.ts file was changed, then no worry about the compile action. However I had no luck to locate the compiled output (.js)

Answer (score 0):

> Yes... I have no idea about how is this working, but if this is similar thing how C/C++ include header files work, then my question makes sense.

`.d.ts` Need to be parsed and analyzed to be able to provide type checking in other parts of your TypeScript project. If you don't want them, then delete them from your project. But if you do .... then they will be used.

> I've also tried to locate where the output of this compile build step (for jquery.d.ts) is located.

There is no output for `.d.ts` files. These are **JUST** used for type checking.

Comment: It seems to me this build action setting is a mistake + it has not effect. I mean, I've turned it to none, still all is working, including type checking for jQuery etc.

Comment: Yes. For `.d.ts` build action has *zero* effect

Comment: Also I've noticed they are compiled (and raise errors if any) even if they are Build action: none, **and** not included to any .ts file with the /// <reference path=".... directive. Very amateur approach, I expected better and I though I missed something.